How to configure my libraries and dependencies to compile my App as static
I am Programming an App with visual studio 2022, in c++, x64 with libraries installed with help of vcpkg. They are dynamic link libraries.
I want to use my App as static, to run it in another PC without need to install frameworks, or make an installer, or other dependencies, just one .exe and that´s it. Maybe is called "Portable"?
My AI asistent says that I should first change to Release, and change Code generation option to "/MT"
I do it and  I started to experiment Linking problems, of course because my libraries are configured as dynamic. But...
Is that exactly the problem that I have in this message?, or do I have more? I can really not understand the Message.
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::locale __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::getloc(void)const " (__imp_?getloc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QEBA?AVlocale@2@XZ)    WxWidgets_Structured    C:\Users\Juan\source\repos\WxWidgets_Structured\ConfigManager.obj   1   
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  WxWidgets_Structured    C:\Users\Juan\source\repos\WxWidgets_Structured\x64\Release\WxWidgets_Structured.exe    1   


Side note: Compiling a program with everything linked statically is not always possible - just saying. You may also want to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

"My AI asistent says" - Word of advice; stop listening to that chat bot with no actual intelligence. I don't understand why people try to use these "AI" tools when writing code. More often than not they do more harm than good and they certainly have no clue what they are talking about.

Side note: The Error List is an executive summary of the problems in the code. It leaves stuff out, sometimes the bit of information that would have cracked the case wide open.  The Output tab usually found right beside the Error List tab is the full, raw, and unadulterated build diagnostic output in plain text. It can be intimidating as all hell, but it leaves nothing out and, if it doesn't solve the problem for you, it pastes really easily into a Stack Overflow post.

x64 with libraries installed with help of vcpkg Did you use one of the triplets that create static libraries? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-updates-static-linking-is-now-available/

My AI asistent says that I should first change to Release, and change Code generation option to "/MT" That is a small part of the solution but far from the the full story. Every library you use also needs to be built as a static library with static runtime. Not just your application. Also as @JesperJuhl mentioned in the first comment this is not always possible.

The __declspec(dllimport) means it expects to link to an import library for a dll.

Thanks, for the links and tips they were helpful.
I will change all posible to static and try again.
But I really want to trace back this message, what is the exactly way to trace the problem?
I write here the #includes of my .ConfigManager.cpp and ConfigManager.h
#include "ConfigManager.h"
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include 
and
#pragma once
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include "Data.h"
#include 
There are more libraries that are no static, why is appearing the linking error only one time?

As soon as you want to use something that you get through a DLL you cannot build a statically built program. Full stop.
Possible ways:

most libraries come in either dynamic or static libraries: verify (twice) whether the packages that you use are provided also as static libraries

there are a number of one file packaging program tools. For example py2exe or pyinstaller take a Python interpretor, one or more scripts and the required libraries, pack everything into a kind of zip archive along with a bootstrap that unpacks everything into a temporary folder and then launch the Python interpretor with its main script. You could probably adapt a self-extracting zip file to immediately launch your program after extracting the archive containing the program and the required DLL.
But that actually boils down to first building an installer and then have the installer immediately run the code and clean the installation after use. You could search whether InnoSetup of NSIS can be tweaked to obtain that...



One of my libraries is not available in static. So I will try your second option.

I did install all the libraries:

nlohman-json
vtk
wxwidgets
open62541

in his static version sucessfully using:
./vcpkg install <packet>:x64-windows-static
./vcpkg integrate install

new start of visual studio, and changing to "/MT"
but..
Exactly the same problem is happening...
how can I continue?
Should I eliminate the references to .dll in properties and addin a link to the static libraries? Or is vcpkg doing it automatically.
If needed, how can I do it?
